# requests disappear after queueing in scrapy

Tags: python-3.5, scrapy

Scrapy seems to complete without processing all the requests. I know this because i am logging before and after queueing the request and I can clearly see that.

I am logging in both parse and error callback methods and none of them got called for those missing requests.

How can I debug what happened to those requests?

Comment: did you add `dont_filter=True` when re-queueing the request?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Bingo! it worked but I am not sure why would scrapy drop it because in the entire 50 URLs, that URL had no duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `dont_filter=True` when re-queueing the request. Though the request may not match other request but Scrapy remembers what requests it has already made and it will filter out if you re-queue it. It will assume it was by mistake.