# How to handle temporary errors which are not signaled by http status code?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am writing a crawler using Scrapy (Python) and don't know how to handle certain errors.

I have got a website which sometimes returns an empty body or a normal page with an error message. Both replies come with a standard 200 HTTP status code.

What I want to do when I encounter such a situation is tell Scrapy to

- don't save the response to cache (I am using `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True`) as the content for a successful request looks different
- reschedule the request
- reduce request rate (I am using `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True`)

Is there an easy way like raising a certain exception a la `raise scrapy.TemporaryError` or do I have to do everything manually. In the later case, how do I delete content from the cache or talk to the autothrottle module?

I know I can use `dont_cache` on requests to not cache them. But usually I do want to cache my requests and only decide on the response if I want to keep it. Also the documentation is not clear weather this flag avoids saving the response of the request to cache **or** if it also avoids reading the request from cache...

Autothrottle uses the download latency to adjust the request rate. The [throttling algorithm](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#throttling-algorithm) treats non-200 responses as failed responses and does not decrease the download delay. However my requests return 200 status codes. So autothrottle cannot handle the situation. There must be a way to tell autothrottle to use its throttling logic and treat these specific requests as failed.

Answer (score 1):

In your response you can check for a condition and decide to re-queue the URL.

[requests disappear after queueing in scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466345/requests-disappear-after-queueing-in-scrapy/46466842#46466842)

```
def parse(self, response):
    if blank_data or should_rescrape:
       yield Request(respone.url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.response)
```

**Adjusting throttle dynamically**

If you check `self.crawler.extensions.middlewares`, you will see that it has all loaded extensions

In my case

`self.crawler.extensions.middlewares[5]` gives `<scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle object at 0x10b75a208>` (Of course you will loop through the tuple and find which one is of type `AutoThrottle`)

[image: Throttling]

Now you can use this object and adjust the values dynamically in your scraper

Comment: Yes thank you. But this doesn't help me with caching or throttling. Usually 'bad' responses are returned pretty quickly, so this way I will just queue lots of requests and overload the server.

Comment: What is your queue length when you requeue the url? So you want these urls to be queued for at least X amount of time?

Comment: My queue is not very large (thousands), but all requests are to the same server, so any requests might exhibit this behavior. I want autothrottle to go into effect (which uses the download latency to adjust request delay). However bad responses don't have a large latency, they are returned from the server pretty much instantaneously. So I want to tell autothrottle that I just received a bad request and it should start slowing down requests until it hits a rate which doesn't yield bad requests anymore.